# mcp23008 problem

Tags: i2c

i am using mcp23008 that is a i/o expander ,everything is OK but in datasheet there is a capacitor and i don't know what is that doing ,also i didn't see it in any designed board that i found in internet . 
do you know what is that and it is necessary to use or not
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This capacitor is only used in Microchip's testing setup for deriving "real world" rise / fall times of data edges - it models the input impedance of other devices connected to the I2C bus. You don't need to include it in your circuit, and in fact it would be a very bad thing if you did as it would increase the load capacitance on the line - which ideally you want to be low.